# Simple check authentication decorator in Python + Pylons

Tags: python, pylons, decorator

I'd like to write a simple decorator that I can put above functions in my controller to check authentication and re-direct to the login page if the current user is not authenticated.  What is the best way to do this?  Where should the decorator go?  How should I pass cookie info to the decorator?  Sample code is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Another approach for authorization in pylons (decorator based, repoze.what like)](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Another+approach+for+authorization+in+pylons+%28decorator+based%2C+repoze.what+like%29)

> How should I pass cookie info to the
>   decorator?

Use a global request object and get cookie or use wsgi environ of the request